# How to position a block at the bottom in the region-body

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm generating an invoice PDF and i want to have the **`block`** with the VAT Summary **positioned at the bottom of the `region-body`**

I read (almost) all the ibex and the more general `xsl-fo`documentation and the closest i got was to learn how to absolutely position elements in the page;

But that does not suit my needs because i may have many lines with variable size and the absolutely-positioned element may overlap the lines.

I am using ibex xsl-fo generator.

**EDIT: Some sample code**

The full xsl-fo code can be found [here](http://penpaste.com/bz1v9ea)

I put some sample code below so that one does not have to see the original xsl-fo that's 1200 lines long.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'I am up here'"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <!-- I'd like this table-row to be bottom aligned -->
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'I would like to be at the bottom of the region body'"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    <xsl:template
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please share your generated FO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this in XSL FO is to use page templates for the last page and put that content in the region-after. There is no structure that yields a "rubber-banding" effect to push the content to the bottom, nor does float="bottom" exist (which would not work in your case anyway if it dod not fit, it would float to the bottom of the second page. You would use something like this from another project I have done.

```
 <fo:layout-master-set>
    <!-- ============== simple-page-master ============ -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple-page-master.only" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="4.15in" margin-right="0.25in" margin-bottom="2.6in" margin-left="0.25in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="792pt" region-name="region-before.only"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <!-- ============== simple-page-master ============ -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple-page-master.first" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="4.15in" margin-right="0.25in" margin-bottom="2.6in" margin-left="0.25in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="792pt" region-name="region-before.first"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <!-- ============== simple-page-master ============ -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple-page-master.rest" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="0.8in" margin-right="0.25in" margin-bottom="0.64in" margin-left="0.25in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="792pt" region-name="region-before.rest"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <!-- ============== simple-page-master ============ -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple-page-master.last" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="0.8in" margin-right="0.25in" margin-bottom="2.58in" margin-left="0.25in" />
      <fo:region-before extent="792pt" region-name="region-before.last"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <!-- ============== page-sequence-master ============ -->
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="page-sequence-master">
       <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="no-limit">
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master.last" blank-or-not-blank="blank" />
         <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master.only" page-position="only" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master.first" page-position="first" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master.last" page-position="last" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master.rest" page-position="rest" />
       </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives> 
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
```

This creates templates for pages that are first, rest, last and a special one of only (where first is last). You then output that content you wish at the bottom of the page into the appropriate regions (both region-before.only and region-before.last).

The only caveat/trick is if you choose different sizes of page layout to accommodate the information you want at the bottom, then you should make sure the last few rows of the inside of your table are kept together to pull a few of those rows to the second page.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply but i had no time to properly read this. 
If i may, One more thing: Is there anyway to put the region after on "fit to size" that is "grow as much as you need". So far i am only able to set a fixed size.

Answer (score 3):

You could have used an `fo:footnote` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_footnote) either in the last table row or possibly immediately after the table.

If you use an empty `fo:inline` for the footnote marker, no marker will show in the `fo:region-body`, and you can put an `fo:table` for the VAT summary in the `fo:footnote-body`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the footnote it's a good solution as @Tony says in the reply above.
For me this solution works:

Yes, for me this code works.

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:footnote>
        <fo:inline/>
        <fo:footnote-body>
            <fo:block keep-together.within-column="always">
                <fo:inline>
                    <xsl:text>Here is the text at the bottom</xsl:text>
                </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
    </fo:footnote>
</fo:block>
```